# How do you use the client.delete_channel() command in pythons for discord bots

Tags: python, discord.py

I need to know how to use the delete_channel command in discord.py may someone please post a code sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you'd delete channels using a command

```py
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import discord

bot=Bot(command_prefix='.')
```

This is in the `async` version, probably the version you're using

```py
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def del_chan(msg,channel:discord.Channel):
    await bot.delete_channel(channel)
```

This is in `rewrite`

```py
@bot.command()
async def del_channel(msg,chan:discord.TextChannel):
    await chan.delete()
```

To use the command you'd do `.del_chan #channel_name`, `.del_chan channel_name`, `.del_channel #channel_name`, or `.del_channel channel_name`

Comment: thankyou I was having trouble using it I want to clear my channel using this I want the bot to delete the channel move the people create a new one that is a clear copy and move everyone back